# IOS Object field being set to nil unexpectedly

Tags: ios, nsmanagedobject, null

I know I must be doing something stupid, but haven't been able to figure this one out.
I have some code that is parsing an xml file.  The objects are mostly NSManagedObject types.
One of them (InvoiceItem) has a field "category" that is a reference to another NSManagedObject.  So while parsing, I look up the reference and make the assignment.
The next InvoiceItem happens to reference the same Category, and as soon as that category object is assigned - the reference in the previous InvoiceItem gets set to nil!

I can't include all the code, since there is a LOT of it.
Here is the relevant block:

```
  for (int i = 0; (i < invoice.invoiceItems.count); i++) {
     NSLog(@"InvoiceItemParser: didStartTag[A,%d]: ii = %ld, cat=%ld", i, (long) ((InvoiceItem *)[[invoice invoiceItems] objectAtIndex:i]), (long) ((InvoiceItem *)[[invoice invoiceItems] objectAtIndex:i]).category);
  }
  ii.category = (ChargeCategory *)[self.db getObjectOfType:@"ChargeCategory" withDBID:catid];
  NSLog(@"InvoiceItemParser: didStartTag[B]: ii=%ld, cat=%ld", (long) ii, (long) ii.category);
  for (int i = 0; (i < invoice.invoiceItems.count); i++) {
     NSLog(@"InvoiceItemParser: didStartTag[C,%d]: ii = %ld, cat=%ld", i, (long) ((InvoiceItem *)[[invoice invoiceItems] objectAtIndex:i]), (long) ((InvoiceItem *)[[invoice invoiceItems] objectAtIndex:i]).category);
  }
```

the "self.db getObjectOfType" is actually just looking it up in a cache map, and returning the reference from the map.

The output looks like this for the 1st pair of objects:

```
InvoiceItemParser: didStartTag[B]: ii=164718368, cat=361986368
InvoiceItemParser: didEndTag[B]: ii=164718368, cat=361986368
InvoiceItemParser: didEndTag[C]: ii=164718368, cat=361986368
InvoiceItemParser: didEndTag[D,0]: ii = 164718368, cat=361986368
InvoiceItemParser: didStartTag[A,0]: ii = 164718368, cat=361986368
InvoiceItemParser: didStartTag[B]: ii=361994624, cat=361986368
InvoiceItemParser: didStartTag[C,0]: ii = 164718368, cat=0
```

Note the category on object 164718368 is there just before the assignment to object 361994624, and gone just after.

This always ends up with just the last reference to any category object being valid.  All previous references in the run are nil'd out.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inverse relationship on category to invoiceItems is probably not set at all or is a "to-one" relationship. It needs to be a "to-many", otherwise the previous items get nil-ed.

Comment: Yes!  That was it!  That flag hadn't been set.
THANK YOU!